# En build.gradle(proyecto) tengo que aplicar esta linea y no me la toma

Tags: flutter, vscode, build.gradle

En el 3er punto en la consola de firebase que dice "Agrega el SDK de Firebase" dice "Agrega el complemento como una dependencia a tu archivo build.gradle de nivel de proyecto:
Archivo de Gradle de nivel de raíz (nivel de proyecto) (/build.gradle):

```
plugins {

  // ...


  // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin

  **id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.0' apply false**

}"
```

Estoy trabajando en VS. Code y si bien encontre el buil.gradle a nivel de proyecto, lo más cercano, y consultando con Bard es colocar la depenencia en la parte de **"dependencies"** del archivo **build.gradle a nivel de proyecto**.
Cuando quiero hacer un **gradle clean build** , me da error en la linea agregada.
Quiza no es realmente el lugar donde aplicar dicha dependencia en ese formato.
Agradezco de antemano me den alguna info al respecto. Gracias!

Adjunto captura del requerimiento.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Lee bien la documentación](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin?hl=es-419). En el archivo `app/build.gradle` debes poner esto: **`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`**, eso va en el root del archivo, fuera de cualquier apartado. Y en el `build.gradle` del proyecto, dentro de `dependencies` debes poner esto: **`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'`**

Comment: Muchas gracias!